# URL Migration in cloudfoundry from V1 to V2

Tags: cloud-foundry

I have deployed couple of my Apps in Cloudfoundry V1. Now as the Eco system is getting migrated to V2 I want to know what would happen to my access URLs.

Following are the APPs and their access URL's I have as of now.

App Name        App URL

```
Platform            shopzyplatform.cloudfoundry.com
Testplatform       testplatform.cloudfoundry.com
imagebox          imagebox.cloudfoundry.com
```

Now even after migrating to V2 I want to continue with above highlighted URLs  as some of my clients are pointing to these URLs directly.

Kindly let me know how can I retain these URLs...

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately after June 30th, those URLs will no longer work as the datacenter where Cloud Foundry v1 is running is being decommissioned.

If you migrate the apps to v2 (available now at run.pivotal.io and you can login with your v1 credentials) then you will get new URLs for your apps which end in cfapps.io by default. However, v2 also now supports custom Domains. Unfortunately you will not be able to use cloudfoundry.com as the root domain as that is already taken, but you could choose your own custom domain for your new v2 "organisation" and then map your three apps onto that.

Comment: Thanks a lot Andy. I am now trying with the custom domains.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The short notice and the lack of redirection is extremely unfriendly to existing users, however. I think you would burn a lot less goodwill, if you add a simple redirection service...

Comment: We do in fact have a redirection service, for up to 60 days, and if you visit this thread in our support forums you can request it. http://support.cloudfoundry.com/entries/24235668-URL-migration